# Moving link from entire div to element within

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have multiple codeblocks in my DOM that look something like this:

```
<a href="unique.html">
    <div>
        <p>content</p>
        <form method="get">
            <button type="submit">Continue</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</a>
```

For project-related reasons i can only alter this code after-the-fact with JS or JQuery. How can i change it in a way, that not the whole div acts as a link anymore, but just the button and each div retains its unique link?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to do it and then ask a specific question if you run into trouble with your code for doing it.

Comment: Note that the "before" structure above is invalid, you can't have interactive content (a button) inside a link. So when you go to fix that, you'll need to ensure the button is not inside the link. Also note that since the structure is invalid, the browser could well reorganize it for you (a quick check with Chrome shows it doesn't, didn't check others), meaning what you're operating on at runtime may not be what it looks like in the HTML (and may vary from browser to browser).

Comment: Bottom line: The requirement you've been given is unreasonable. Push back. That structure needs to be corrected *before* it goes to the browser.

Comment: `$("div>p>form>button").unwrap()`

Comment: T.J.Crowder i can not push back, this is how the out-of-the-box system works. What i want to do is alter it in a way that instead of the whole div being a link, only a button is.
So the quesiton is, how to retain the url and attribute it to the link.

Comment: mplungjan, if i understand that correctly, this would remove the link from the div. How can i do the second step of my quesiton, add that functionality to the button?